# stop code execution until XMLHttpRequest cycle is complete

Tags: javascript, callback, xmlhttprequest, promise

Your Google Maps code structure looks something like this:

```
<script>
function initMap() {

}

var locations = 
[
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181}
]
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-key&callback=initMap" >
</script>
```

The thing is, you want to populate `locations` via a call to the server (using XMLHttpRequest , i.e. a vanilla JavaScript AJAX call because you don't want to use jQuery).

And you don't want the second script block (the call to the Google Maps API) to execute until  `locations` has successfully been populated.
How would you achieve this via any of the following:

- A Callback ?
- JavaScript Promises ?
- Any other method you can think of?

Also, is [a semaphore, as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031458/1883050) a viable way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
function initMap() {
  var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     LoadGoogleMaps();
    }
  };
  xhr.open();//<-- Your parameters go here
  xhr.send();
}

function LoadGoogleMaps(){
  // Logic to load maps
}
```

Standard XHR documentation can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Semaphores are a nice idea in concept but can sometimes be extremely difficult to implement. Typically in javascript it's best practice to use callbacks or promises when possible.