# why java script doesn't stack inside the while loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check values from a database through sending the values by for loop in ajax request to php file, "each value in request" then the file return variable called "avl" `if $data["avl"]==1` so it is available if not it is not available.

The problem is that I check a stream of values and they all must return `1` to continue my process, but the condition doesn't wait until the for loop ends to check. It checks the condition before the for loop starts, even the code is not like that. Ex: it does the condition in line 100 before for loop ends in line 50.

```
var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
var avl_qty = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]

    var titleElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')[0]
    var item = titleElement.innerText
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var freequantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-free-input')[0]

    var quantity = quantityElement.value
    var freequantity = freequantityElement.value

    alert("before avilability ajax")

    $.ajax({
        url: "checkavlqty.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {

            item: item,
            quantity: quantity,
            freequantity: freequantity
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data["avl"] == 0) {
                alert("inside condistion")
                avl_qty = 0;
            }
        }
    })

}

alert(avl_qty)
```

It always alerts `1`, even the final value of avl_qty is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax call you are doing inside the loop is asynchronous, this means that when the execution reaches the `$.ajax[...]` line, it will run "in the background" while the normal execution continues through the loop.

What is most likely happening in your code is that the execution will reach the `alert(avl_qty)` line before the ajax responses from the loop reach you. You can test this by letting the script run. You'll see that it will execute the `alert("before avilability ajax")`, then `alert(avl_qty)` and finally all the `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` from the ajax requests.

To solve the issue you will have to wait for the async calls to finish, [you can use async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or even callbacks, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031421/how-to-make-code-wait-while-calling-asynchronous-calls-like-ajax).

Comment: this means that all ajax requests run asynchronous?  sorry for this silly question but i an new in development

Comment: No worries, there's no silly questions. Yes, an AJAX request is always async. If you want more info about the jQuery ajax method you're using you can [read it here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).